# How to fix a "money sorter" java program

Tags: java, currency

So basically, I am learning in college to code in Java, I've had my first lessons, and now I was challenged to make a "coin sorter" program with if's and whiles.
The objective of the program is giving it an amount of money in Euros and it is supposed to return it organized in the most efficient way, prioritizing higher value bills.
My program is written with some variables in Portuguese so I'll explain:
(double dinheiro;) is the variable where I store the amount of money.
and then the coins go from left to right in the int list of the code, starting at the 50€ bill and ending at the 1 cent.

The program works fine and does what it is supposed to do for all the "Euros" objects I create where the money (dinheiro) is an int value (no cents) and until it's something like 34,50 for example, where it's just 50 cents. It wouldn't work for 34,20 or 34,60 or anything like that for example.

When I try to run anything with those values, it doesn't output any error or anything like that, it just leaves the program infinitely running with no output (and ends up taking 100% of the processor and overheating the computer).

I'm quite tired and have been looking for a while for an answer and trying to debug it myself but I just can't find what I did wrong in such a probably simple thing, so I'm quite frustrated.

Thank you!

```
public class Euros {

    private double dinheiro;
    private double n50, n20, n10, n5, m2, m1, m50c, m20c, m10c, m5c, m2c, m1c;

    public Euros(double dinheiro) {
        this.dinheiro = dinheiro;
    }

    public void distribuirDinheiro() {
        do {
            if (dinheiro >= 50) {
                dinheiro = dinheiro - 50;
                n50 = n50 + 1;
            } else if (dinheiro >= 20 && dinheiro < 50) {
                dinheiro = dinheiro - 20;
                n20 = n20 + 1;
            } else if (dinheiro >= 10 && dinheiro < 20) {
                dinheiro = dinheiro - 10;
                n10 = n10 + 1;
            } else if (dinheiro >= 5 && dinheiro < 10) {
                dinheiro = dinheiro - 5;
                n5 = n5 + 1;
            } else if (dinheiro >= 2 && dinheiro < 5) {
                dinheiro = dinheiro - 2;
                m2 = m2 + 1;
            } else if (dinheiro >= 1 && dinheiro < 2) {
                dinheiro = dinheiro - 1;
                m1 = m1 + 1;
            } else if (dinheiro >= 0.5 && dinheiro < 1) {
                dinheiro = dinheiro - 0.5;
                m50c = m50c + 1;
            } else if (dinheiro >= 0.2 && dinheiro < 0.5) {
                dinheiro = dinheiro - 0.2;
                m20c = m20c + 1;
            } else if (dinheiro >= 0.1 && dinheiro < 0.2) {
                dinheiro = dinheiro - 0.1;
                m10c = m10c + 1;
            } else if (dinheiro >= 0.05 && dinheiro < 0.1) {
                dinheiro = dinheiro - 0.05;
                m5c = m5c + 1;
            } else if (dinheiro >= 0.02 && dinheiro < 0.05) {
                dinheiro = dinheiro - 0.02;
                m2c = m2c + 1;
            } else if (dinheiro >= 0.01 && dinheiro < 0.02) {
                dinheiro = dinheiro - 0.01;
                m1c = m1c + 1;
            }
        } while (dinheiro > 0);
    }
```

Comment: You'd need to read up on floating point numbers and why you shouldn't use it for money. A quick check in jshell tells you what first operation will result in. jshell> 34.20 - 20 $1==> 14.200000000000003   See the problem?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's too big of a question but what is a floating point number? And a double is a floating point number? And in that case what kind of variable should I use? And it doesn't work because the value becomes too big?

Comment: Why do you use endless loop instead of if(denheiro >0). In Do-while loop , While will be checked after Do is completed even though while is false , but only once. You have to be careful with endless loops

Comment: @GipsyKing Your condition is the same as his. The problem is that you should never rely on exact results from floating point values. This causes the infinite loop!

Comment: okay so now I place an if(dinheiro > 0) before the while, replaced the do-while for just a while and replaced the while condition, instead of while(dinheiro > 0) to while(dinheiro >= 0.01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I really recommend you using Operator abbreviations so your code is easier to read, for example:

`dinheiro = dinheiro - 0.5;`

can be abbreviated to:

`dinheiro -= 0.5;`

As for your problem, as @Worthless said on comment, you should never use floating point data type for currency operations, since in between test and calculations, a lot of precision is lost and also, you cannot make enough if's for every decimal that a double can handle, you should really check out on BigInteger or BigDecimal classes, which you can read about [here](https://dzone.com/articles/never-use-float-and-double-for-monetary-calculatio)

Comment: As long as you stay within the boundaries of the precision of the floating point data types everything should be ok. This program can be fixed by checking if `dinheiro >= 0.01`. After this small fix it works perfectly.